# Generating a link dynamically with urlrewrite

Tags: jsf, url-rewriting, hyperlink

I am using urlrewriting and my pattern matches `../products/product_id` and maps to `/product.jsf?product_id=$1`.

The rewriting performs well, but I am having trouble generating dynamic links.

In a context of iteration:

```
...
  <h:link value="view product" outcome="products/#{item.id}"/>
...
```

The case is very simple. I just want the url generated has the form "products/123", but the page doesn't render, I guess because the outcome cannot be resolved at generation time.

I could just generate a link with "/product.jsf" and add a view parameter. But I prefer the other way. How can I have this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried adding the app name in the outcome target as in /appnane/products/#{item.id}

Comment: Trying to combine REST in a webapp? Think of it this way: When `products/123` hits FacesServlet, what do you expect the controller to make of it? What you want is based on the REST principle, implement it separately and you'll be fine

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a valid navigation case outcome, just use plain HTML `<a>`.

```
<a href="products/#{item.id}">view product</a>
```

Depending on the current URI, you may only need to prepend the context path yourself.

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/products/#{item.id}">view product</a>
```